# Transfer wordpress site to a different host

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog hosted on wordpress.com which i wish to transfer to a different hosting agency. Please what are the procedures for doing this. Can anyone also refer me to an article on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Come on, this is easily Googled. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-your-blog-from-wordpress-com-to-wordpress-org/

Answer (score 0):

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

use this plugin. it works realy well and is all free.

Comment: It's a wordpress.com site, he can't install plugins. https://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress.com's official guide for migrating to self-hosted is here:
https://move.wordpress.com/

It covers everything from finding hosting to migrating your domain, content, subscribers and stats.